# Removing all reference to a linked server on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've been charged with the task of moving a database from ServerA to ServerB. ServerB contains many other database objects, a fair few using a Linked Server connection to ServerA. For example, there may be a view which joins a table1 on ServerB to ServerA.database.schema.table1

Does anyone know of a script I can run on ServerB that will display a list of all objects that reference ServerA, so that I may update them quickly, without having to open each object.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has the potential for false positives, but that is probably better than relying on dependency views (which will miss dynamic SQL or simply out-of-date dependencies):

```
SELECT 'EXEC sp_helptext ''' 
 + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]))
 + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([object_id])) + ''';'
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%ServerA.%';
```

You may also need to account for potential cases where the server name is enclosed in square brackets:

```
OR definition LIKE '%\[ServerA\].%' ESCAPE '\';
```

You should also consider using [SYNONYMs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to prevent this type of maintenance in the future. In fact you may also want to check for any synonyms that reference the server name:

```
SELECT name, base_object_name
  FROM sys.synonyms
  WHERE base_object_name LIKE 'ServerA.%'
  OR base_object_name LIKE '\[ServerA\].%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty much an ideal answer as far as I can tell